Why does this error occur? error: could not compile `stellar-xdr` (lib) - Debian 12.5

Running on Debian 12.5
cargo 1.79.0 (ffa9cf99a 2024-06-03)

Compilation started with :
$ cargo install --locked stellar-cli --features opt
What I've Tried

Had this happen so I rebooted the box and tried again.
Got the same error.
Cloned my Rust app ran it via Cargo and everything compiled & ran. (confirms that Rust seems to work)

Snapshot of the hang:

Since it was failing on this openssl thing I checked the version of openssl on the machine:
3.013-1~deb12u1
Full Error Dump
Here's the entire dump that I see after numerous items compile successfully:
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: /home/raddev/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name stellar_xdr --edition=2021 /home/raddev/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/stellar-xdr-21.1.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=87 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="alloc"' --cfg 'feature="base64"' --cfg 'feature="cli"' --cfg 'feature="curr"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="hex"' --cfg 'feature="next"' --cfg 'feature="schemars"' --cfg 'feature="serde"' --cfg 'feature="serde_json"' --cfg 'feature="std"' -C metadata=af8c870d6c705c78 -C extra-filename=-af8c870d6c705c78 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps -C strip=debuginfo -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps --extern base64=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libbase64-1b35ea8a03ec0dcd.rmeta --extern clap=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libclap-a79a4a5972ceaea2.rmeta --extern escape_bytes=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libescape_bytes-f3448e9443fa5151.rmeta --extern hex=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libhex-dae29e29dc8bcf85.rmeta --extern schemars=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libschemars-b3f12c2113ee3532.rmeta --extern serde=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libserde-db72848c19d1343a.rmeta --extern serde_json=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libserde_json-bfebf2827b11271c.rmeta --extern serde_with=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libserde_with-bd737b47dde0b722.rmeta --extern stellar_strkey=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libstellar_strkey-d479ce9b8eeae612.rmeta --extern thiserror=/tmp/cargo-installHkhOH9/release/deps/libthiserror-a204a15f627b0e6e.rmeta --cap-lints allow (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)

I believe I found the answer.
I had only given the Debian 12.5 VirtualBox 1 processor and 2 GB RAM.
I now upped it to 4GB ram and 4 processors and it almost successfully built.
It did finally fail after getting maxed out (as shown in image).
I'll go back now and give it more ram and see if it will complete.

You will not get this built without at least:
6 CPUs & 6.5GB RAM
Mine just barely completed, but the issue is resolved.  Build is complete.

